# (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext

Tags: ios, swift

I read that this line of code gets the managed object context from AppDelegate.

```
let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

I read the Apple documentation of each word to try to reconstruct the right overall output sense mentioned above.
Who can explain in a clear and detailed way the meaning of this line syntax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you access the `UIApplication` class.

This is a singleton. There is only one instance of it which is created upon application start by the cocoa touch framework.

Then you access its one and only instance by calling the class method `sharedApplication`. "shared(classname)" is a common name for the method reurning the instance of a singleton. Another common name is "sharedInstance".

Then you access its `delegate`. That follows the usual delegation pattern that you see quite often in iOS app development using cocoa touch. But this is a very special delegate which you own. It is the `AppDelegate` class. 
When you let Xcode create a new app project using core data, then it creates some standard methods into your `AppDelegate` class for your convenience.

One of these is a (computed) getter for `managedObjectContext`.

However, `UIApplication` knows its delegate only as any object that implements the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol. The additional methods for core data are not known to `UIApplication`.

That is why you have to cast the output of `.sharedApplication()` to your implementaion named `AppDelegate`. `as` is the cast operator in Swift.

After it was casted you can actually access the getter `managedObjectContext`.

That's it.

Comment: I am also looking answer of this question. It's really a nice answer.  I am almost clear. But i am confuse here "However, UIApplication knows its delegate only as any object that implements the UIApplicationDelegate protocol. The additional methods for core data are not known to UIApplication" .  Can you explain this point more details. Thanks.

Comment: @bir, the delegate is declared as something like `id <UIApplicationDelegate> delegate;` And that is what your receive from `UIApplication.sharedApplication()`. Therefore you need to cast the return value to the class of your implementaion of `UIApplicationDelegate` which apparently is `AppDelegate`.