# Access AppDelegate functions in tableview controller?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication

We are using Swift and we made a "UITableViewController" inside our project folder. We are trying to access our "AppDelegate" functions. We have tried using

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

We have also tried

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

We also have

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

inside our "ViewController" and it works there.

The error is " Use of undeclared Type 'AppDelegate' "

Comment: What "isn't working?"  Are you getting a syntax error?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe it can be done another way. Have you tried making those functions public? 'public func ...'? Can you not access the App Delegate or the functions inside?

Answer (score 0):

Change that line to

```
let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this answers the question.  I don't see any information about Core Data in the question.

Comment: @JAL I don't know the answer, but I think it's here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521401/uiapplication-sharedapplication-delegate-as-appdelegate-managedobjectcontext

Comment: This has nothing to do with Core Data or `NSManagedObjectContext`.  In addition, if you feel that this question is a duplicate, you should flag it as such.

Comment: If you've the answer, please post it.